# How to convert Django dynamic page to static HTML file?

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

The current website is running on Django, Gunicorn and nginx. I want a way to convert the current front page into a static HTML page and want nginx to serve this static page instead of going through the whole web stack. I want the front page to load faster. This can be done manually, but is there a tool integrated with Django or Gunicorn that automatically convert certain page into static and serve those pages?

Answer (score 0):

put it in your /media/ folder

then just point to

some.url/media/html/some_static_html.html